# Blinking lights on new fan

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I recently bought a new fan with light kit from a box store.  This is the third fan of this model and I've had no issues with the others.  Upon getting everything hooked up, the fan works great, but the lights "strobe" every few seconds.  Thinking the problem had to be with the light kit only, I took that part back and swapped it and the bulbs out, hoping to not replace the whole fan.  Well, I was disappointed to replace those bits and to find that the lights were still doing the same thing.

The previous fan & lights had no such issue, it was just and old (and wobbly) fan so I decided to replace it.  So is it likely the fan/wiring itself, or is it possible that it could be some sort of power issue?  It's just going to be a lot of work to take the whole thing down, so I want to get it right the first time.  Any suggestions to verify the issue are appreciated.

Comment: What make and model of fan are you using, and what are you using for bulbs?

Comment: What kind of switch(es) do you have?

Comment: Try swapping the bulbs with known good from another fan. You will then know where the problem is.

Comment: The fan is a Harbor Breeze Notus.  I have 2 others with no issues.  The switches are Leviton Decora (the same switches I have in the other 2 rooms with these fans).  The bulbs are the ones that came with the fans and when I went out and swapped out the light kit, I also swapped out the bulbs with another set.  I figured that it was not likely a bulb issue, since they were all doing it, but decided it would be safest to swap them out.  Exact same issue I had with the first light kit and fan.

Comment: Update:  Okay so I may be attributing this problem to the wrong thing - We were out of town for a week and just got home prior to me starting this fan replacement project.  It turns out though, that we have the blinking happening on other lights we hadn't noticed before - although I'm pretty sure this must have just started, so I don't think the problem is tied to the fan.  However, the blinking lights seem to all be happening on the same breaker.  Any suggestions there?

Comment: Just for closure on this - I had an electrician in the house for suggestions on something else and he said that he thinks the issue is probably the bulbs themselves are very sensitive and we could try others.